# Jackson serialization: Ignore uninitialised int

Tags: java, json, serialization, null, int

Now first off, I've read some other answers on this site and others about jackson serialisation but they all provide methods for ignoring `null` fields. In Java, however, `int` cannot be `null`.

I am trying to `ObjectMap` a java object to convert to `Json` but to ignore any `null` fields. This works for strings but `int`s end up taking on a value of `0` if uninitialised, and since `0` is not `null` the field is not ignored.

```
    private ObjectWriter mapper = new ObjectMapper().writer();
    private myClass data = new myClass(); //class contains a string and int variable
    data.setNumber(someInt); //set values
    data.setString(someString);

    String Json = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
```

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

EDIT: To clarify, I have tried using the `Integer` class as the data type but causes the conversion to a `Json` string to throw a JsonProcessingException.

Comment: What type is `data`? What error do you get? Show the class you're trying to serialize.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide more information.

Comment: Please show `myClass` and the error stack.

Comment: myclass can consist of anything, and for this question's sake, only contains an int with it's getters and setters. And there is no error stack because I've caught the exception.

Comment: @Shiri - Then print the exception, when you catch it and then copy it here. Changing "int" to "Integer" does not cause error itself, the error is somewhere deeper. Using Integer instead of int for json serialization is completely legit.

Comment: It was a NullPointerException Error. `Failed.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)`

Comment: @Shiri Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the Jackson JsonInclude annotation:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
```

works around the problem where unassigned primitive types always assumes a default value; in this case, unassigned `int`s become `0` and are subsequently ignored.

Answer (score 7):

Use int wrapper [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). This way you'll be able to use `null` value.

Alternatively you can use [Jackson's JsonInclude annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-inclusion) to ignore null value when serializing.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)  
public class MyClass{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. The annotation only works for non_null but the int initialises as 0 by default because int cannot be null. I think my problem has something to do with Integer serialisation by Jackson like Libik was saying.

Comment: Well it's hard to help without seeing the class you're trying to serialize. You shouldn't have problem with `Integer`.

Answer (score 5):

Change `int` to `Integer`.

Otherwise no, it is not possible to have int variable with null in any way.

Comment: I've tried this, the conversion, `String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(data)` just fails in this case.

Comment: @Shiri The accessor methods should be updated as well to return/set `Integer` class.