# Jackson convertValue to a List but return null

Tags: java, json, jackson

The json string is like this:

```
[
   {
     "id":1545043316459,
     "user_id":127118102570729472,
     "username":"abcd",
     "phone":"12413453563",
     "password":"b6b33aad5c337315d4ac5a34d82db990cfaf22e5eefe27220b6827d5e66ad8b4",
     "license":"12351331",
     "plate":"abcdef",
     "avatar":"",
     "approval":0,
     "balance":0.0
   }
]
```

When I use `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` to convert this json to a `List<User>`, the method returns null. However, when I changes the field "approval" to 1, the convertion succeeds. 
Th class `User`'s constructor is as below:

```
@JsonCreator
public User(@JsonProperty("user_id") long userId, @JsonProperty("username") String username, @JsonProperty("password") String password, @JsonProperty("avatar") String avatar,
                @JsonProperty("phone") String phone, @JsonProperty("license") String license, @JsonProperty("plate") String plate, @JsonProperty("approval") int approval,
                @JsonProperty("balance") BigDecimal balance) {
   this.userId = userId;
   this.username = username;
   this.password = password;
   this.avatar = avatar;
   this.phone = phone;
   this.license = license;
   this.plate = plate;
   this.balance = balance;
   this.approval = approval;
}
```

I have applied `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson serialization: Ignore uninitialised int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372004/jackson-serialization-ignore-uninitialised-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson ignores primitive types with default value.

To fix this you can :

1. Put annotation on field **approval**

   ```
   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
   ```
2. Change type from `int` to `Integer`

Solution is up to you