# Jackson serialization ignore negative values

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an Object like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private int number;
    // ...
}
```

And I want to include the `number` only if the value is not negative (`number >= 0`).

While researching I found [Jackson serialization: ignore empty values (or null)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089651/9662601) and [Jackson serialization: Ignore uninitialised int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33372004/9662601). Both are using the `@JsonInclude` annotation with either `Include.NON_NULL`, `Include.NON_EMPTY` or `Include.NON_DEFAULT`, but none of them fits my problem.

Can I somehow use `@JsonInclude` with my condition `number >= 0` to include the value only if not negative? Or is there another solution how I can achieve that?

Comment: As you would normally convert the object jackson converted into another object (it's external data and its good practice to convert external data into your own data structures to not rely on them in your business logic) I would suggest you to implement the outlined logic in the conversion process as jackson should not be used to implement logic that is specific to your application and thus your business logic. You may be able to achieve this but then you coupled application specific logic to your json mapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Jackson 2.9+ version, you could try with a `Include.Custom` value for `@JsonInclude`.
From [the `JsonInclude.CUSTOM` specification](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#CUSTOM) :

> Value that indicates that separate `filter` Object (specified by
>   `JsonInclude.valueFilter()` for value itself, and/or
>   `JsonInclude.contentFilter()` for contents of structured types) is to be
>   used for determining inclusion criteria. Filter object's equals()
>   method is called with value to serialize; if it returns true value is
>   **excluded** (that is, filtered out); if false value is **included**.

That is a more specific and declarative approach than defining a custom serializer.

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = PositiveIntegerFilter.class)
private int number;

// ...
public class PositiveIntegerFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
       // Trick required to be compliant with the Jackson Custom attribute processing 
       if (other == null) {
          return true;
       }
       int value = (Integer)other;
       return value < 0;
    }
}
```

It works with `objects`and primitives and it boxes primitives to wrappers in the `filter.equals()` method.