# Exclude 0 from JSON response in Jackson Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have a POJO like this.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {

    private int a;

    private String b;
}
```

I want to exclude the property 'a' if it has 0 value. String b is excluded with

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Only way I could thing of is convert the int data type to Integer Object and set the value to NULL in the setter explicitly if it is 0.

Any other suggestions or correct solution will be appreciated

Comment: I think your way to change `int` to `Integer` is correct, since primitive types has default values (in this case `0` for `int` fields) and `0` (as `int`) can not be compared to `null`.

Comment: But here is a another solution that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353643/2201165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Do what you said: Change `int` to `Integer` and use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`. Because primitive types have default values and their values cannot be compared to `null` you have to wrap the `int` to `Integer`. See [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). imho this is the cleaner way.

**Option 2**:

Use the way described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372004/jackson-serialization-ignore-uninitialised-int/45353643#45353643) and use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)` instead (see [Jackson-annotations API](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT)), so that default values (and so also `null` values for objects) will be ignored.

---

*Note*:

If you only want to exclude the specific field (in your case the `int`/`Integer` - `a` - field) when it has a `null`-/default value and the other fields (in your case the `String` - `b` - field) should be included when they have `null`-/default values, put the annotation on field level.